# Can I call function by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to to run function for searching word in database. The function is in this location: media/search, up to now it was possible to run this function with this JS by "search_query":

```js
final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);   
    var queryTextField = document.getElementById("search_query");  
    queryTextField.value = final_transcript;       
   ....
```

"search_query" is id in this input:

```html
<form class="input-group navbar-form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>media/search" method="post"></li>
                <li style="margin-top:8px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search subtitles..." id="search_query" name="string" /></li>   
                <li style="margin:8px><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="btn_search"><i class="search "></i></button>
```

I want to change it so I don't want to use this HTML code. I want to implement "calling" function media/search in JS instead of:

```js
 var queryTextField = document.getElementById("search_query");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I misunderstood you, but if I understand you correctly, you want to trigger the search with javascript?

And it looks like you want to do this without jQuery?

```
//get search string inputted by user
var queryTextField = document.getElementById("search_query");
var query = queryTextField.value

//pass base url to javascript
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>'

//create new request
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

//set up what you want to do with returned data
request.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  //if call was successful
  if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
  {  
     //response will be in here  
     //request.responseText;
  }
}

//set as post, the url, send asynchronously
request.open('POST', base_url+'media/search', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(query);
```

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: base_url+'media/search',
  data: query,
  success: function(data_return) {
    //do something with returned data
  }
});
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

and

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I have not tested the above code, but it should put you on the right path.